# awk syntax error in utilizing a shell variable with if/then statement

Tags: if-statement, variables, awk, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get the following code to work but I keep on getting syntax errors in the awk portion of the script.

Briefly, I want to calculate a cutoff value and store it as a floating decimal in a numerical variable (e.g., cutoff). I want to pass this variable to the awk script which I try but still run into syntax problems with errors that state:

```
    awk: syntax error at source line 3
       context is
           >>> <<<
```

Here is the following sample sequences could have the first four lines of file `Spl-129-run10_xx.fa`:

`>Spl-129_TTCAGTGG_80`
`CAGACATAGTCATCTATCAATACATaGATGATTTGTATGTAGGATCTGACTTAGAAATAGGGCAGCATAGAACAAAAATAGAGGAACTGAGACAACATCTGTTGAGGTGGGGATTTACCACACCAGACAAAAAACATCAGAAAGAACCTCCATTCCTTTGGATGGGTTATGAACTCCATCCTGATAAATGGACAGTACAGCCTATAGTGCTGCCAGAAAAGGACAGCTGGACTGTCAATGACATACAGA`

`>Spl-129_TGGGGACC_80`
`CAGACATAGTCATCTATCAATACATaGATGATTTGTATGTAGGATCTGACTTAGAAATAGGGCAGCATAGAACAAAAATAGAGGAACTGAGACAACATCTGTTGAGGTGGGGATTTACCACACCAGACAAAAAACATCAGAAAGAACCTCCATTCCTTTGGATGGGTTATGAACTCCATCCTGATAAATGGACAGTACAGCCTATAGTGCTGCCAGAAAAGGACAGCTGGACTGTCAATGACATACAGA`

and now the code:

```
    for file in *fa; do
        name=`echo $file | cut -d'.' -f1`;
        awk 'BEGIN{RS=">"}NR>1{sub("\n","\t"); gsub("\n",""); print RS$0}' $file | tail -n+2 | sed 's/_/\t/g' >tmp;
        m=`cut -f3 tmp | sort -nr | head -n1`;
        cutoff=`echo "(-1.24*10^-21*$m^6)+(3.53*10^-17*$m^5)-(3.90*10^-13*$m^4)+(2.12*10^-9*$m^3)-(6.06*10^-6*$m^2)+(0.018*$m)+3.15" | bc`;
        echo "$name\t$cutoff";

        awk -v c="$cutoff" -v n="$name" '{ 
            if (c < 4) 
           awk '$3 > 2' tmp >n"_CUT.txt"; 

           else awk '$3 > c' tmp >n"_CUT.txt"; 
    }';
    done
```

The expected output should be a tab-delimited file (e.g., "Spl-129-run10_CUT.txt") in the example form of

`>Spl-129        TGGGGACC        80        sequence`

At the end of the day, I want to utilize the calculated cutoff variable above to filter sequences less than the cutoff (using the value in the third field as comparison) with the condition that if the cutoff is less than 4, then the cutoff of 2 will be used.

Any help that you could provide would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please do add expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: If you could give complete overview of your requirement I am pretty sure we may help better on this one.

Answer (score 0):

The awk sniplet has multiple issues. In particular, there seems to be unnecessary calls to `awk`, from within the `awk` script:

```
 awk -v c="$cutoff" -v n="$name" '{ 
            if (c < 4) 
           awk '$3 > 2' tmp >n"_CUT.txt"; 

           else awk '$3 > c' tmp >n"_CUT.txt"; 
    }';
```

Without additional details (and sample input), it hard to provide a working solution. Consider posting sample input and output. In particular, it's not clear how the calculation of cutoff should be performed from the input.